# How to implement event binding solutions onto dynamically created items considering my project construction

Tags: javascript, event-handling

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
(function()
{
   //add item to the cart
   const cartBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.bi- 
   shopping-bag4');

     cartBtn.forEach(function(btn)
     {
         btn.addEventListener("click", function(event)
         {
              //code goes here...
         })
     })

     //remove item from the cart
     const deleteBtn= document.querySelectorAll('.zmdi-delete');
     cartBtn.forEach(function(btn)
     {
         btn.addEventListener("click", function(event)
         {
             //code goes here...
         })
     })

})();
```

**add item to the cart**: dynamically appends created 'div' element as a child inside its parent div.

**remove item from the cart**: removes those dynamically appended items from the cart with element.remove() function.

The delete button doesn't alert click event. I know that I must implement something that binds remove event with the dynamically appended elements but the solutions in the [binding event on dynamically created elements](http:////https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) don't solve my problem or its likely that I could't properly implement it in my project pattern.
What I have done so far:

1) I tried to add jquery `fn.on` on the eventListeners, I simply changed the js syntax `btn.addEventListener("click", function(event)`  with  jquery's `$(btn).on("click", function(event)`

2) I tried to implement pure js solution :

```
function hasClass(elem, className) {
    return elem.classList.contains(className);
}

const cartBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.bi-shopping-bag4');         
cartBtn.forEach(function(btn)
{
    btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) 
    {
      if (hasClass(event.target, 'bi-shopping-bag4')) {
        // ..bi-shopping-bag4clicked
        // Do your thing

    }, false);
})

const deleteBtn= document.querySelectorAll('.zmdi-delete');
deleteBtn.forEach(function(btn)
{
    btn.addEventListener('click', function (event) 
    {
      if (hasClass(event.target, 'zmdi-delete')) {
        // ..bi-shopping-bag4clicked
        // Do your thing

    }, false);
})
```

but to no avail..So what have I done wrong?

Comment: "*the solutions in the "binding event on dynamically created elements" don't solve my problem*" - why do you think that? Yes they do. Have you tried implementing those solutions? What went wrong? Please show us your attempt so that we can advise how to fix it.

Comment: @Bergi I have edited and explained broadly what I have done and not succeed. Please check it out again.

Comment: It seems like you misunderstood those solutions. You will need to add the event listener to `document` (or whatever common ancestor all the buttons have), not to each individual button. You do not need to apply `querySelectorAll` (as that gives you a *static* list) and you do not need to loop.

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean by '"document"? elements that have an id? document.GetElementById?

Comment: No, I mean the `document` object itself. Alternatively, the `document.documentRoot` element, or - as I said - any element that is a common ancestor of all the (current and future) buttons on which you want to handle events.